# Changing Redmine URL structure and adding other domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I have set up a Redmine installation on a Windows server using the BitNami stack.

I would like to

- change the path of the URL that is used to address redmine at the moment (`www.example.com/redmine/...`) if possible without physically relocating the installation.
- map additional subdomains to certain projects (`www.example2.com` pointing directly at what is now at `www.example.com/redmine/projects/projectname`)

I am apt in Apache configuration, but a total Ruby / Rails newbie and at the moment, can't delve into it as deeply as I want to because of time constraints.

I'd appreciate pointers to HOWTO's and good documentation on how to apply such changes to a standard setup. A list of configuration files that I need to take a look into might already do as well, I just don't yet know my way around a Ruby application.

The stack consists of

- Redmine 0.9.3
- Apache 2.2.14
- MySQL 5.1.30
- Ruby 1.8.7-2010.01
- Rails 2.3.5
- RubyGems 1.3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a pretty active forum for the BitNami stack. First forum results:

- [Rewriting the Redmine URL on Windows](http://bitnami.org/forums/forums/redmine/topics/domain-name-and-site-directory)

working through that now. Additional input is still welcome of course.